# How to prevent multiple firing on click events

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Hi have a bootstrap lightbox (ekko lightbox) that loads a gallery by data-remote attributes. My problemi is that i have loaded a modal footer by data attributes. In my footer I have added a button identified by id="submit". Then I have associated to this button a click action that ia used for send the file name to a PHP page by an ajax request. My action is loaded like this `$(document).on("click", "#submit", function(){/* my ajax call */});` now if the popup modal is shown n times, the ajax request is sent n times. How i fix this issue?

Comment: If you want to make the ajax call only once or the first time, you can simply have a boolean and check that boolean before making an ajax call.

Comment: I used .one() that fix this problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have te same problem. I can't resolve this, but i did the following code to "fix" this problem:

```
$(".glyphicon-picture").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function (){
        var a = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
            if ($("#ekkoLightbox-"+i).attr("id") != undefined) a.push($("#ekkoLightbox-"+i).attr("id"));
        }
        for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
            $("#"+a[i]).remove();
        }
        $(".ekko-lightbox").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
            $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        });
    }, 750);
})
```